# How do I handle dynamic list of <DataColumn> Widgets to avoid RenderFlex exceptions in Flutter DataTable Widget?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a flutter DataTable (in a Container) that is constructed dynamically (values read from API).

Specifically, when it pulls in the columns it throws a RenderFlex exception.  The same values used statically pose no problem.

```
Widget bodyData() => DataTable(
  columns: colWidgets, // set in setState() function 
  rows: rowWidgets // set in setState() function ,
);

...

colWidgets = ListofValues.map((value){
  return new DataColumn(
    label: Text(value)
  );
}).toList();
```

What is the best way to prepare the DataTable for these  values via something like Padding or SingleScrollView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by moving the DataColumn widgets into a FittedBox widget within a Column widget.  The key thing is that the parent/ancestor must have a flex property which the Column provides.

Comment: Would you care sharing some code pls? Thx